# How can I build Skia for iOS?

Tags: ios, build, skia

I try to build skia for iOS. The newest version is not supported by the gyb builder. How else can I build skia for iOS?

I have tried to use CMake and imported the project into XCode. But this approach did not work.

Comment: Please show your code, and what you did so far

Comment: I just want to build skia as a static lib for iOS plateform.  but I do not know the way.